# Running mongodump from within a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to be able to run the `mongodump` utility from within a docker container because the developers on my team do not have the utilities installed locally. So, I created a node script, `export.js` that handles running the tool and also zips the output.

Ideally what I want is to be able to run an npm script:

```
{
  "db:export": "docker build -t some-local-container -f docker-images/Dockerfile.export && docker run some-local-container"
}
```

some-local-container would have access to the `node_modules` and the `export.js` script I would like to run. It would also run this script as the default ENTRY. Obviously, it was built with both node and mongo installed.

My question is vague, but, is there an easier way to do this? I feel like this is overkill for what I want to do. This is a development only script so it didn't seem to make sense living within the Dockerfile for our Mongo instance.